# Error publishing jar with Gradle on Artifactory 'PublishingExtension'

Tags: gradle

Daer all

trying to deploy and artifact I get this error, how I can solve this issue in Gradle version 2.2.1

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
        defaults {
            publications ('mavenJava')
        }

* What went wrong:          
Extension of type 'PublishingExtension' does not exist. Currently registered extension types: [DefaultExtraPropert
iesExtension, DefaultArtifactPublicationSet_Decorated, ReportingExtension_Decorated, DefaultProjectSourceSet_Decor
ated, DefaultBinaryContainer_Decorated]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll share some insights that might explain what's happening. There's not enough detail here for me to know for sure if my insights apply exactly to this situation.

Typically the extension gets registered via the plugin for the root project or subproject that it is contains the plugin during the gradle configure phase.  During the gradle execution phase when the task associated with the plugin gets called, the task queries to obtain the extension.  In your case, the error message is indicating that the extension it needs hasn't been registered and it lets you know the list of extensions that are available for this project or subproject. Two things that I can think of that may cause this are either 1.) the plugin has a bug where the extension is not registered (or sometimes not register - due to some other masked error), or 2.) you are trying to access this extension from a project or subproject that doesn't have this extension registered to it.  More than likely, the second case is what's happening here.

Here's a concrete example.  A com.android.library plugin subproject cannot directly access AppExtension, but the com.android.application plugin can access the AppExtension directly.  That said, the com.android.library plugin project could indirectly access the AppExtension by using project.rootProject to obtain the AppExtension.

My gut tells my that's probably what's happening, but again there's not enough info provided here to confirm that. I hope my late answer proves itself useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it's because of the order of plugins being applied in build.gradle

This didn't work

```
apply plugin: 'com.xxx.yyy:an-internal-plugin'    // depends on PublishingExtension
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
```

This works:

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'com.xxx.yyy:an-internal-plugin'
```